# Manually start a Kubernetes CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

For a deployed Kubernetes CronJob named `foo`, how can I manually run it immediately?  This would be for testing or manual runs outside its configured schedule.

Answer (score 12):

You can start a job based on an existing job's configuration, and a cronjob is just another type of job.

Syntax:
`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/$CronJobName $NameToGiveThePodThatWillBeCreated`

e.g.:
`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/foo foo-manual-1`